# Return value and keep members of javascript object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to work out someone else's code and I'm really stuck on how they've managed to do this. The code is very long so I'll try and give a simplistic example of what I'm trying to find out.

I have something like the following:

```
var obj = function(){
this.obj1 = "test1";
this.obj2 = "test2";
};

var inst = new obj;
alert(inst);
```

This outputs [object]. What I would like to know how to do, is to make the value of this return "test1" instead - BUT also still enable me to call the object members such so that I could also do

```
alert(inst.obj2);
```

And get an output: 'test2'.

The way I thought I could do it was something like:

```
var obj = function(){
    this.obj1 = "test1";
    this.obj2 = "test2";
    return this.obj1;
};

var inst = new obj;
alert(inst);
```

but this also returns [object]

This is what the code I am trying to decipher seems to be doing. The syntax is much more complex - it uses closures and prototype I think, but I am still not getting my head around these so don't really understand what's going on.

Many thanks!

Comment: This might help you out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FIntroduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make `alert` show something other than `[object Object]`, define the `.toString()` method on your object.

```
function MyObj() {
    this.obj1 = "test1";
    this.obj2 = "test2";
};

MyObj.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.obj1;
};

var inst = new MyObj();
alert(inst);   // will show "test1"
```